# How to eliminate space in input string of lex code?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, yacc, lex

I am making a regular expression in lex for using it in yacc accepting arithmetic expressions. I want to eliminate blank space when the expression has a blank space I tried \s but the space is not getting eliminated and my yacc then gives syntax error because \s is not an operator.

**LEX**

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include "y.tab.h"  
int yylval;/*declared extern by yacc code. used to pass info to yacc*/  
%}

letter  [A-Za-z]
digit   ([0-9])*
op      "+"|"*"|"("|")"|"/"|"-"
ws      [ \t\n\r\s]+$
other   .

%%

{ws}    { /*Nothing*/ }
{digit} { yylval = atoi(yytext); return NUM;}
{op}    { return yytext[0];}
{other} { return yytext[0];}

%%
```

Comment: The space character can be represented in a character class as itself.  Your problem appears to be that your `{ws}` macro is anchored to the end of the line.  Remove the `$` at the end of its definition, and also the `\s` inside the character class, and it ought to work better for you.

Comment: Ya that's working thank you @John I am grateful. I am new to lexers & yacc so kinda getting confused.